# IP tables catch xmas scans / null scans

Tags: firewall, iptables, nmap

im trying to use the below rules to can xmas scans and null scans however when testing I have checked my logs and unable to find the prefix?

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j LOG --log-prefix "DROPPED XMAS PACKET:" 
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j LOG --log-prefix "DROPPED NULL PACKET:"
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP
```

What have i got wrong or am i missing something ?

Comment: Maybe logging isn't configured right ? Can you see them in `dmesg` ?

Comment: cant find anything in dmesg tryed searching for the string.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Nmap man page](http://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-techniques.html), a Null scan would send a packet with no flags set, and a Xmas scan would send one with the FIN, PSH, and URG flags set. Your match for null scans looks like it should work, but your Xmas rule should be:

```
 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL FIN,PSH,URG -j LOG --log-prefix "DROPPED XMAS PACKET:"
```

Also, these packets will not be part of an established TCP session, nor will they establish one. For that reason, it's possible that you have a rule earlier in your ruleset that is dropping these packets, since you are using `-A` (append) to add your rules.